# Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying get the datepicker in ng-grid i am getting the error like "Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker"  after adding the gridOptions
enableCellEditOnFocus:true, and i want to highlight cell and the row after editing

i have the below requirements
1)how to get access the last edited cell in ng-cell to apply the css
2)how to apply css class to last edited row i mean class like

```
.red{
   background:red;
   color:white; 
}
```

in particular to last edited row i used row Template although it is working fine on mouse click but is not working on "enter key editing " in ng-grid 
Please help i am new to  angular js  still learning

please refer to below the link

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

app.directive("jqueryDatepicker",function(){
  return {
  link:function(scope,elm){
    angular.element(elm).datepicker();
   }
  }
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50,dob:"1/08/1989"},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,dob:"1/07/1989"},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27,dob:"23/09/1988"},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29,dob:"26/09/1988"},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34,dob:"05/05/1987"}];  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        enableCellEdit:true,
        enableCellSelection:true,
        enableColumnResize:true,
        enablePinning:true,
        enableCellEditOnFocus:true,
        columnDefs: [
           {field:'dob', displayName:'DOB',pinned:true,
        cellTemplate:'<input jquery-Datepicker="" type="text" ng-model="row.entity.dob"/>'},
          {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name',pinnable:false}, 

        {field:'age', displayName:'Age',pinnable:false}
 ],
         beforeSelectionChange: function (rowItem, event) {
                                                $scope.rowItem=rowItem;
                                                $scope.rowId = rowItem.rowIndex;
                                                $scope.initialValue = clone($scope.myData[$scope.rowId]);              
                                          console.log($scope.initialValue)
                                                return true;
                                            },
    };
    function clone(obj) {
      if (obj == null || typeof (obj) != 'object')
          return obj;
      var temp = obj.constructor(); // changed

      for (var key in obj)
          temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);

      return temp;
      };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6h5JIJeCkARNGWQgzeJ9?p=preview

Comment: you can use angular-ui utils which does already implements jquery datepicker.

Comment: with this date picker popup is not coming i tried adding cellTemplate like <input ui-date ng-model="row.entity.dobrow.entity.dob"> not able to get datepicker